# How can I reconnect a disconnected emulator to adb server without killing the server?

Tags: adb, emulation, bluestacks, reconnect

At first, I ran 11 Bluestacks instances like this:

[image]

After some time using self made macro, one instance disconnected like this:

[image]

I just want reconnect emulator-5614 without killing adb server because other bluestacks instances are still running by my macro.

So I tried to reconnect the instance to sever by adb commanding at CMD, but I failed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`adb connect`  is for tcp/ip connections, which it seems you are not using.
It's not clear how the emulator got disconnected, however if it's still running, try

```
adb reconnect device
```

to force reconnection.

Comment: I typed in CMD like this: adb reconnect device //CMD do not reconnect emulator but output a message "Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.32" with very long adb command lists. So I tried like this: adb reconnect emulator-5614 // same result.

Comment: Upgrade to something like `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41`